# How can I make the dropdown sub-menu background stretch across entire menu width

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a site at:

[Development](http://dev.icsandbox.com)

and I want to make the sub-menu background stretch across the entire width of the menu, left to right, without changing where the text appears.

Here is some relevant code from the menu:

```
<li  id="menu-item-11214"  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-11106 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-11214 fusion-dropdown-menu"  ><a    href="http://dev.icsandbox.com/expertise/">Expertise <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li  id="menu-item-11248"  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-11248 fusion-dropdown-submenu"  ><a    href="http://dev.icsandbox.com/overview-3/">Overview</a></li>
    <li  id="menu-item-11215"  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-11215 fusion-dropdown-submenu"  ><a    href="http://dev.icsandbox.com/families-individuals/">Families &#038; Individuals</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li  id="menu-item-11275"  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-11275"  ><a    href="http://dev.icsandbox.com/tax-advisory-3/">Tax &#038; Advisory</a></li>
        <li  id="menu-item-11277"  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-11277"  ><a    href="http://dev.icsandbox.com/trust-estates/">Trust &#038; Estates</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I have tried a few things and I get weird results. The background will begin where the text is and stretch out the number of pixels I assign, but each new parent menu shifts the sub-menu to the right. What I want is the menu to look like:

[Production](http://seiler.com)

Answer (score 0):

Use psuedo elements to stretch the full width.
Something like...

```
ul li ul {
    position: relative;
}
ul li ul:before,
ul li ul:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 999999px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
ul li ul:before {
    right: 100%;
}

ul li ul:after{
    left: 100%;
}
```

I've added a working example below using a single div.

```css
.full-width-please {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: green;
}
.full-width-please:before,
.full-width-please:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 999999px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.full-width-please:before {
    right: 100%;
}

.full-width-please:after {
    left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width-please"></div>
```